# How can I avoid a constant when I want a global object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am want to add S3 file storage to my rails 5 application. Since I am using heroku I used their [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#s3-sdk) which says to just create a constant named `S3_BUCKET` in your `config/initializers/aws.rb` and you can use that constant everywhere.

The heroku code looks like this:

```rb
#config/initializers/aws.rb

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
```

The problem with this is that I have to override this constant for the specs to work.

I have this alternative solution (which is sadly not working):

```rb
#lib/aws_helpers/s3.rb

module AWSHelpers
  module S3
    class << self
      attr_accessor :configuration

      def configure
        self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
        yield(configuration)
      end

      def bucket
        @bucket ||= Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(configuration.s3_bucket)
      end
    end

    class Configuration
      attr_accessor :s3_bucket, :aws_access_key_id, :aws_secret_access_key_id
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
#config/initializers/aws.rb

AWSHelpers::S3.configure do |config|
  config.s3_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  config.aws_secret_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
end
```

What I want to be able to do in a controller is:

```
AWSHelpers::S3.bucket.object(a_key)
```

Unfortunately this fails and tells me that `bucket` method can't return anything because the configuration is nil.

What I know:

1. the aws initializer gets executed and when I add `puts` in all the methods I can see the correct output when my server starts via `rails s`
2. the controller knows about the service module or it would not even get to the `bucket` method
3. the code works when I dump the content of `config/initializers/aws.rb` into the controller

I really would like to know why the code above is not working. It seems to set up everything correctly and then when I want to use it in the controller suddenly things are as if i'd never called `configure`.

I am also open to other suggestions on how to do this. Just using the constant is not an option because it has to be changed for the specs to work.

Comment: Why does setting something in the initializer seem wrong to you?  You can set a class variable using the @@my_variable but It is strongly discouraged IMO.  Personally I would do it in the initializers if every user of the app will be using the same S3 bucket.  If you need different buckets for different users you may consider using session storage but I think the initializer is the right place for this.  Care to elaborate on what issue you are running into with your tests using the initializer?

Comment: Defining global constants in an initializer is absolutely fine in Rails. Just make sure you don't mutate them, and if you find yourself defining way too many of them maybe reconsider what you're doing. If you're getting warnings about constants changing, double check to make sure that nothing is setting them. Also you can add `.freeze` to any constant to prevent it from being mutated. That may be what your specs are complaining about.

Comment: I have tried to clarify my problem. Setting everything up in a initializer is what I want to do. I would love the code I have to just work. 

I need to have a stub object for the bucket for the specs to work.

Answer (score 0):

This code might look strange, but it's actually exactly what you'd want in this situation. Keep in mind this situation is a bit irregular, it's for configuring a plugin that has external API dependencies and associated keys that must be populated before the rest of the code works.

It's ugly from an implementation perspective, but from a usability perspective it's nice. You can just do `AWSHelpers::S3.configure do |config|` as shown in the initializer. All that code is to make those semantics work properly.

Comment: The code is what I want in this situation. I am glad you agree with me there. The issue is that the code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap trick, but it works.

in `config/application.rb`:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    def s3_bucket
      @s3_bucket ||= begin
        # your stuff
      end 
    end 
  end
end 

Rails.application.s3_bucket.object(a_key)
```